# How to use LIKE in SQLDF in R for searching text in multiple dataframes

Tags: r, string, sqldf

I have 2 dataframes with text and want to compare partial string.
What I am looking for is Id, t1.mo and monthid from table 2.

```
t1 <- data.frame("id"=1:4,"mo"=c("Jan","Feb","Apr","Mar"))
t2 <- data.frame("id"=1:4, "nt"= c("January","Jan Feb","February","Mar"),"monthid" = 5:8)

sqldf("select t1.mo,t2.nt,t2.monthid from t1, t2 where t1.mo like '%' || t2.nt || '%'")
```

I have tried,
`sqldf("select t1.mo,t2.mo from t1, t2 where t1.mo like '%Feb%'")` and its working
But when referencing `t2` it is not working.

```
T1.id  t1.mo  t2.monthid
1       Jan    5
2       Feb    6
4       Mar    8
```

Any help is appreciated.

Edited the output as Tim Biegeleisen pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the `LIKE` comparsion backwards, and you should be checking that the `mo` column from `t1` appears as a substring of the `nt` column in `t2`:

```
sql <- "SELECT t1.mo, t2.nt, t2.monthid
        FROM t1
        INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.nt like '%' || t1.mo || '%' AND t1.id = t2.id"
result <- sqldf(sql)
```

Also note that I have refactored your query to use a proper *explicit* join, which is the preferred way of writing SQL.

### Demo

[image: screen capture of demo]

Note that I am getting an extra record in the result set beyond what you expect, but this is because `Feb` in the first table matches both `Jan Feb` and `February` in the second table.  If you only expected one match there, you should state why.

Comment: Thanks very much for editing the question and the answer, Tim Biegeleisen. I have to join the tables on id so added t1.id=t2.id and it worked.

Comment: Adding that join also does not generate the result set you expect.  You should clarify your expected output.

Comment: Thanks. I was expecting rows with id match. so adding id match gave "Feb".
id  mo      nt monthid
1  1 Jan January       5
2  2 Feb Jan Feb       6
3  4 Mar     Mar       8

May I should change the output in question too. sorry for the confusion.